# Display a css style using the get url in php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to display a content that have a style css and im using the $_GET function of php my code is working but when I put a font-color style the url will be destroy,

> example= "&text=`<p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></p><ol><li><font
>   size="7">dummy</font></li><li>dummy</li><li><font+color="#33cc33">dummy</font></li><li><font+color="#993399">dummy</font></li></ol><p></p>`"

What should be the best solution with this problem

Comment: why `+` between `font` and `color`?

Comment: First of all use php default url encode and decode functionality to over come this issue.

Comment: this is for the url im using the $_GET function in php to view the content

Answer (score 0):

try this code ..........

example= "&text=

```html
<p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></p><ol><li><font size="7">dummy</font></li><li>dummy</li><li style="color:#33cc33">dummy</li><li style="color:#993399">dummy</li></ol><p></p>
```

"

Comment: sir this code is for the url,i want to fetch this using the $_get